# Does charity contributions come under itemized deductions of California state w4 form?

Tags: united-states, taxes, california, form-w-4, state-taxes

1. I am trying to understand why State of California has no line for charity contributions or I may be something. For example, in the Worksheet B of this [form](https://www.edd.ca.gov/pdf_pub_ctr/de4.pdf), line 1, it only talks about the [itemized deductions](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/file/personal/deductions/index.html). But if you refer the itemized deductions they don't cover anything pertaining to charity?
2. As per the above itemized deductions, I don't have anything, which basically means there is nothing in WorksheetB that counts for me?
3. And I do not want to withhold any additional taxes, does WorksheetC is only for additions withholdings?

Overall, I can't believe I only have one allowance throughout this entire form which makes me think that I am doing it wrong. Can someone please help me with the above 3 questions.

Answer (score 2):

Your linked form [DE4](https://www.edd.ca.gov/pdf_pub_ctr/de4.pdf), page 3, worksheet B, line 1 indicates that you should estimate your California itemized deductions based on the FTB form 540 schedules.

Form [540](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018/18_540.pdf), line 18 indicates that schedule CA is used for calculating itemized deductions.

Form 540 [Schdule CA](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2018/18_540ca.pdf), part II lines 11-14 cover gifts to charity (requires first completing IRS Form 1040 Schedule A).

You'd want to be sure to be aware of differences between allowable deductions on Federal forms vs California forms, as well as documentation requirements; see for example [**Tax deduction - Charitable contributions and others**](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/about-ftb/newsroom/tax-news/march-2019/tax-deduction.html).

For a single tax filer, having one allowance on a form W4 (or DE4) is common, rather than unbelievable.  It may or may not fit your situation, but by itself it's no indication that you are doing something wrong.